# Trying to get property of non-objec for ErrorController.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling

i use ZF 1.12.3

in index i have

```
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');
```

error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in application/controllers/ErrorController.php on line 28
```

in this line i have

```
$errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');
```

i fond solution to add

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->throwExceptions(false);
```

to boostrap - but it dont solove my error

application.ini :

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "mea\"
includePaths.mea = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Vendor/mea"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.view[] =
appnamespace = "Application"


[staging : production]


[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Error Controlerr:

```
<?php

class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Application',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
        ));

        ZendX_JQuery::enableView( $this->view);

    }


    public function errorAction()
    {


        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        if(!$errors){

        }

        switch ($errors->type) { 
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:

                // 404 error -- controller or action not found
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
                $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
                break;
            default:
                // application error 
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
                $this->view->message = 'Application error';
                break;
        }

        $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
        $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
    }


}
```

Comment: paste your error controller.php and are you using zf >= 1.12 ?

Comment: nothing stands out, it works fine in my app,run this , what does it says, `echo $errors['type']; ` ?

Comment: $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        var_dump($errors); give my null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so thats the problem i think, you dont have any exception but you are trying to run your error controller directly(i dont know why),

try this,

```
 if($errors!=null){        

    switch ($errors->type) { 
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
        case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:

            // 404 error -- controller or action not found
            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
            $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
            break;
        default:
            // application error 
            $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
            $this->view->message = 'Application error';
            break;
    }

    $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
    $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
}
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: yes it help - now i see i have this erro call and this make this problem : $this->_forward('error','error');